# access violation writing location in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I get access violation writing location in face recognizer in opencv when the code getting to this line: model->train(images, labels);

the error:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9B494321B (opencv_core331.dll) in WHomeCamera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000100000014. occurred

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\face.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace face;

int main(void)
{
    vector <Mat> images; // vector of matrix for the images of the faces;
    vector <int> labels; // vector of int's for the labes (each person get      label ex: moshe - 0);

    try
    {
        images.push_back(imread("D:\imagesForProject\1.jpg",    CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // insert the face image;
        labels.push_back(0); // insert his label;

        images.push_back(imread("D:\imagesForProject\2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // insert the face image;
        labels.push_back(0); // insert his label;

        images.push_back(imread("D:\imagesForProject\3.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // insert the face image;
        labels.push_back(0); // insert his label;


    }

    catch(Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "can't open the images" << e.msg << endl; // if we couldn't     open the files cerr it's basic cout for errors;
    }

    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = FisherFaceRecognizer::create();
    model->train(images, labels);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Which compiler? Release and debug build? Where did your OpenCV binaries come from?

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes.

Comment: ... or better yet, use forward slashes.

Comment: it's still not working...

Comment: Why the try/catch? Imread doesn't throw...

Answer (score 0):

`OpenCV 3.3` built by myself using `G++ 5.4` on `Ubuntu 16.04`.

This code works for me. `Do not ask me why`, you `should` find the difference `by yourself`.

---

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace face;

int main(void)
{
    vector <Mat> images; // vector of matrix for the images of the faces;
    vector <int> labels; // vector of int's for the labes (each person get      label ex: moshe - 0);

    try{
        images.push_back(imread("Pictures/test0.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // insert the face image;
        labels.push_back(0); // insert his label;
        images.push_back(imread("Pictures/test1.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // insert the face image;
        labels.push_back(1); // insert his label;
    }catch(Exception& e){
        cerr << "can't open the images" << e.msg << endl; // if we couldn't     open the files cerr it's basic cout for errors;
    }

    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = FisherFaceRecognizer::create();
    model->train(images, labels);
    model->save("xxx.xml");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I copy exactly your code and it's not working (i inserted two people - and there is still error so maybe you are wrong)