# opencv assertion failed C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv

I use opencv 3.3.1 on visual studio 2017 (windows) and when I'm running this code I getting assertion error, do you know why?
(I build opencv from source code with cmake)
the problem happening in this line:    model->train(images, labels);

the error message:
OpenCV Error: 
    Assertion failed (0 <= _rowRange.start && _rowRange.start <= _rowR
    ange.end && _rowRange.end <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file 
    C:\myOpenCv\opencv-3.
    3.1\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 492

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace face;

int main(void)
{
    vector <Mat> images; // vector of matrix for the images of the faces;
    vector <int> labels; // vector of int's for the labes (each person get label ex: moshe - 0);

    try {
        images.push_back(imread("D:\\imagesForProject\\1.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // insert the face image;
        labels.push_back(0); // insert his label;
        images.push_back(imread("D:\\imagesForProject\\2.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); // insert the face image;
        labels.push_back(1); // insert his label;
    }
    catch (Exception& e) {
        cerr << "can't open the images" << e.msg << endl; // if we couldn't open the files cerr it's basic cout for errors;
    }

    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = FisherFaceRecognizer::create();
    model->train(images, labels);
    model->save("xx.xml");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: So where do you get assertion error? Can you post assertion message too?

Comment: Better edit your question and post those relevant messages too

Comment: I don't think imread throws an exception on a failure to read. https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html

Comment: The error you get to me looks like your files were not loaded.

Comment: i checked and the image was loaded

Comment: If you copy my answer, please copy it correct! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857057/access-violation-writing-location-in-opencv/47861641#47861641

Comment: I copied it but it still not working (so i tried to change it, as you can see).

Comment: I copy exactly your code and it's not working (i inserted two people - and there is still error so maybe you are wrong)